# laravel 8 don't worked after admin

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

I tried to add so that the admin can this connected in / login and that when he connects alone he has access 127.0.0.1:8000/dashboard/home and only him has access

````
welcome.blade.php

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-8">
          <div class="row">
            @if (count($categories) > 0)
              @foreach ($categories as $category)
              <div class="col-lg-12">
              <!-- second section  -->
              <a href="{{route('category.overview', $category->id)}}">
              <h4 class="text-white bg-info mb-0 p-4 rounded-top">
                {{$category->title}}
              </h4>
              </a>
              <table
                class="table table-striped table-responsive table-bordered">
                <thead class="thead-light">
                  <tr>
                    <th scope="col">Forum</th>
                    <th scope="col">Topics</th>
                    <!-- <th scope="col">Posts</th>
                    <th scope="col">Latest Post</th> -->
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                @if (count($category->forums) > 0)
                  @foreach ($category->forums as $forum)
                  <tr>
                    <td>
                      <h3 class="h5">
                        <a href="{{route('forum.overview', $forum->id)}}" class="text-uppercase">{{$forum->title}}</a>
                      </h3>
                      <p class="mb-0">
                        {!!$forum->desc!!}
                      </p>
                    </td>
                    <td><div>{{$forum->discussions->count()}}</td>
                  </tr>
                  @endforeach
                @else
                  <p> 0 Forums found in this category</p>
                @endif
                </tbody>
              </table>
            </div>
              @endforeach
            @else
              <h1>No Forum categories found</h1>
            @endif
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4">
          <aside>
            <div class="card">
              <div class="card-body">
                <h4 class="card-title">Members Online</h4>
                <ul class="list-unstyled mb-0">
                  @if (count($users_online) > 0)
                    @foreach ($users_online as $user)
                    <span class="badge badge-pill badge-primary">{{$user->name}}</span>
                    @endforeach
                  @endif
                </ul>
              </div>
              <div class="card-footer">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card">
              <div class="card-body">
                <h4 class="card-title">Members Statistics</h4>
                <dl class="row">
                  <dt class="col-8 mb-0">Total Categories:</dt>
                  <dd class="col-4 mb-0">{{$totalCategories}}</dd>
                </dl>
                <dl class="row">
                  <dt class="col-8 mb-0">Total Forums:</dt>
                  <dd class="col-4 mb-0">{{$forumsCount}}</dd>
                </dl>
                <dl class="row">
                  <dt class="col-8 mb-0">Total Topics:</dt>
                  <dd class="col-4 mb-0">{{$topicsCount}}</dd>
                </dl>
                <dl class="row">
                  <dt class="col-8 mb-0">Total members:</dt>
                  <dd class="col-4 mb-0">{{$totalMembers}}</dd>
                </dl>
              </div>
              <div class="card-footer">
                <div>Newest Member</div>
                <div><a href="#">{{$newest->name}}</a></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </aside>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

dashboard.blade.php

``` <body>
  <section id="container" class="">
    @include('admin.header')
    <aside>
      <div id="sidebar" class="nav-collapse">
        <ul class="sidebar-menu">
          <li class="active">
            <a class="" href="/dashboard/home">
                          <i class="icon_house_alt"></i>
                          <span>Dashboard</span>
                      </a>
          </li>
          <li class="sub-menu">
            <a href="javascript:;" class="">
                          <i class="fa fa-edit"></i>
                          <span>Actions</span>
                          <span class="menu-arrow arrow_carrot-right"></span>
                      </a>
            <ul class="sub">
              <li><a class="" href="{{route('category.new')}}">Create Category</a></li>
              <li><a class="" href="{{route('forum.new')}}">Create Forum</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
         <li>
            <a class="" href="/dashboard/users">
                          <i class="fa fa-users"></i>
                          <span>Users</span>
                      </a>
          </li>

          <li>
            <a class="" href="{{route('categories')}}">
                          <i class="fa fa-users"></i>
                          <span>Categories</span>
                      </a>
          </li>

          <li>
            <a class="" href="{{route('forums')}}">
                          <i class="fa fa-users"></i>
                          <span>Forums</span>
                      </a>
          </li>          

        </ul>
      </div>
    </aside>
    <div id="app">
      @yield('content')
    </div>
  </section>
{{-- ckeditor --}}
<script>
  CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1' );
</script>
    <script>
      $(function() {
        $(".knob").knob({
          'draw': function() {
            $(this.i).val(this.cv + '%')
          }
        })
      });
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#owl-slider").owlCarousel({
          navigation: true,
          slideSpeed: 300,
          paginationSpeed: 400,
          singleItem: true

        });
      });
      $(function() {
        $('select.styled').customSelect();
      });
      $(function() {
        $('#map').vectorMap({
          map: 'world_mill_en',
          series: {
            regions: [{
              values: gdpData,
              scale: ['#000', '#000'],
              normalizeFunction: 'polynomial'
            }]
          },
          backgroundColor: '#eef3f7',
          onLabelShow: function(e, el, code) {
            el.html(el.html() + ' (GDP - ' + gdpData[code] + ')');
          }
        });
      });

```
ressource/views/admin/pages/home.blade.php

```
      <section id="main-content">
        <section class="wrapper">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
              <h3 class="page-header"><i class="fa fa-laptop"></i> Dashboard</h3>
              <ol class="breadcrumb">
                <li><i class="fa fa-home"></i><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                <li><i class="fa fa-laptop"></i>Dashboard</li>
              </ol>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="flash-message">
            @if(\Session::has('message'))
            <p class="alert
            {{ Session::get('alert-class', 'alert-success') }}">{{Session::get('message') }}</p>
            @endif
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
              <div class="info-box blue-bg">
                <i class="fa fa-cloud-download"></i>
                @if ($categories->count() > 0)
                <div class="count">{{$categories->count()}}</div>
                @else
                <div class="count">0</div>
                @endif
                <div class="title">Categories</div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
              <div class="info-box brown-bg">
                <i class="fa fa-users"></i>
                @if ($users->count() > 0)
                <div class="count">{{$users->count()}}</div>
                @else
                <div class="count">0</div>
                @endif
                <div class="title">Users</div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
              <div class="info-box dark-bg">
                <i class="fa fa-question"></i>
                @if ($forums->count() > 0)
                <div class="count">{{$forums->count()}}</div>
                @else
                <div class="count">0</div>
                @endif
                <div class="title">Forums</div>
              </div>
            </div> 
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
              <div class="info-box green-bg">
                <i class="fa fa-comment"></i>
                @if ($topics->count() > 0)
                <div class="count">{{$topics->count()}}</div>
                @else
                <div class="count">0</div>
                @endif
                <div class="title">Topics</div>
              </div>
            </div> 
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12">
              <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                  <h2><i class="fa fa-flag-o red"></i><strong>Registered Users</strong></h2>
                  <div class="panel-actions">
                    <a href="/dashboard/home" class="btn-setting"><i class="fa fa-rotate-right"></i></a>
                    <a href="/dashboard/home" class="btn-minimize"><i class="fa fa-chevron-up"></i></a>
                    <a href="/dashboard/home" class="btn-close"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                  <table class="table bootstrap-datatable countries">
                    <thead>
                      <tr>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Email</th>
                        <th>Rank</th>
                        <th>View</th>
                        <th>Delete</th>
                      </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                      @if (count($users)> 0)
                      @foreach ($users as $user)
                        <tr>
                          <td>{{$user->name}}</td>
                          <td>{{$user->email}}</td>
                          <td>{{$user->rank}}</td>
                          <td><a href="/dashboard/users/{{$user->id}}"><i class="fa fa-eye text-success"></i></a></td>
                          <td><form action="{{ route('user.delete', ['id' => $user->id]) }}" method="POST" >
                            @csrf
                            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" value="Delete">
                              </form></td> 
                        </tr>    
                        @endforeach
                        @endif
                    </tbody>
                  </table>
                  {{ $users->links() }}
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            </div>
          </div> 
        </section>
      </section>
@endsection ```
````

home.blade.php

````
```  @extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
           <section class="content">
               <div class="container">
                   <div class="row">
                       <div class="col-md-3">
                           <div class="card card-primary card-outline">
                               <div class="card-body box-profile">
                                   <div class="text-center">
                                       <img class="profile-user-img img-fluid img-circle" src="{{asset('/images/profile.png')}}" alt="User profile picture">
                                   </div>
                                   <h3 class="profile-username text-center">{{auth()->user()->name}}</h3>
                                   <p class="text-muted text-center">{{auth()->user()->telegram}}<span class="badge badge-success">{{auth()->user()->skills}}</span></p>
                                   <ul class="list-group list-group-unbordered mb-3">
                                        <li class="list-group-item">
                                            <b>Joined</b></br>
                                            <b>Last seen</b></br>
                                            <b>Reaction score</b></br>
                                            <b>Total sell</b></br>
                                            <b>Total purchase</b></br>
                                            <b>Messages</b> <a class="float-right">{{count(auth()->user()->topics)}}</a>
                                       </li>
                                       {{-- <li class="list-group-item">
                                           <b>Following</b> <a class="float-right">543</a>
                                       </li>
                                       <li class="list-group-item">
                                           <b>Friends</b> <a class="float-right">13,287</a>
                                       </li> --}}
                                   </ul>
                               </div>
                           </div>
                           <div class="card card-primary">
                               <div class="card-header">
                                   <h3 class="card-title">About Me</h3>
                               </div>
                               <div class="card-body">
                               {{auth()->user()->education}}
                               </br>Contact tg : {{auth()->user()->telegram}}
                               </div>
                           </div>
                       </div>
                       <div class="col-md-9">
                           <div class="card">
                               <div class="card-header p-2">
                                   <ul class="nav nav-pills">
                                       <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link active" href="#activity" data-toggle="tab">Latest activity</a></li>
                                       <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#timeline" data-toggle="tab">Timeline</a></li>
                                       <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#settings" data-toggle="tab">Settings</a></li>
                                   </ul>
                               </div>
                               <div class="card-body">
                                   <div class="tab-content">
                                       <div class="active tab-pane" id="activity">
                                           <div class="post">
                                               <div class="user-block">
                                                   <img class="img-circle img-bordered-sm" width="5%" src="{{asset('/images/profile.png')}}" alt="user image">
                                                   <span class="username">
                                                       <a href="#">{{auth()->user()->name}}</a>
                                                       <a href="#" class="float-right btn-tool"><i class="fas fa-times"></i></a>
                                                   </span>
                                                   <span class="description">Shared publicly - {{$latest->created_at}}</span>
                                               </div>
                                               @if ($latest_user_post)
                                               <p>
                                                {{$latest_user_post->desc}}
                                               </p>
                                               @else
                                                    <p>
                                                    You have not started any discussion yet
                                                   </p> 
                                               @endif
                                               {{-- <p>
                                                   <a href="#" class="link-black text-sm mr-2"><i class="fas fa-share mr-1"></i> Share</a>
                                                   <a href="#" class="link-black text-sm"><i class="far fa-thumbs-up mr-1"></i> Like</a>
                                                   <span class="float-right">
                                                       <a href="#" class="link-black text-sm">
                                                           <i class="far fa-comments mr-1"></i> Comments (5)
                                                       </a>
                                                   </span>
                                               </p>
                                               <input class="form-control form-control-sm" type="text" placeholder="Type a comment"> --}}
                                           </div>
                                           <div class="post clearfix">
                                               <div class="user-block">
                                                   <img class="img-circle img-bordered-sm" width="5%" src="{{asset('/images/profile.png')}}" alt="User Image">
                                                   <span class="username">
                                                       <a href="#">{{$latest->user->name}}</a>
                                                       <a href="#" class="float-right btn-tool"><i class="fas fa-times"></i></a>
                                                   </span>
                                                   <span class="description">Started a discussion - {{$latest->created_at}}</span>
                                               </div>
                                               @if ($latest)
                                               <p>
                                                {!!$latest->desc!!}
                                               </p>
                                               @else
                                                    <p>
                                                    You have not started any discussion yet
                                                   </p> 
                                               @endif
                                               {{-- <form class="form-horizontal">
                                                   <div class="input-group input-group-sm mb-0">
                                                       <input class="form-control form-control-sm" placeholder="Response">
                                                       <div class="input-group-append">
                                                           <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Send</button>
                                                       </div>
                                                   </div>
                                               </form> --}}
                                           </div>
                                       </div>
                                       <div class="tab-pane" id="timeline">
                                       </div>
                                       <div class="tab-pane" id="settings">
                                           <form action="{{route('user.update', auth()->id())}}" method="POST" class="form-horizontal">
                                           @csrf
                                               <div class="form-group row">
                                                   <label for="inputEducation" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">About you</label>
                                                   <div class="col-sm-10">
                                                       <textarea type="text" value="{{auth()->user()->education}}" class="form-control" name="education" id="inputEducation" placeholder="{{auth()->user()->education}}"></textarea>
                                                   </div>
                                               </div>
                                               <div class="form-group row">
                                                   <label for="inputSkills" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Skills</label>
                                                   <div class="col-sm-10">
                                                       <input type="text" value="{{auth()->user()->skills}}"  class="form-control" name="skills" id="inputSkills" placeholder="Skills">
                                                   </div>
                                               </div>
                                               <div class="form-group row">
                                                   <div class="offset-sm-2 col-sm-10">
```
````

web.php

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
Route::get('/', 'App\Http\Controllers\FrontendController@index');
Auth::routes();
Route::get('/home', [App\Http\Controllers\HomeController::class, 'index'])->name('home');
Route::get('/new-topic', function () {
    return view('client.new-topic');
});
Route::get('/category/overview/{id}', 'App\Http\Controllers\FrontendController@categoryOverview')->name('category.overview');
Route::get('/forum/overview/{id}', 'App\Http\Controllers\FrontendController@forumOverview')->name('forum.overview');
Route::get('dashboard/home', 'App\Http\Controllers\DashboardController@home');
Route::get('dashboard/category/new', 'App\Http\Controllers\CategoryController@create')->name('category.new');
Route::post('dashboard/category/new', 'App\Http\Controllers\CategoryController@store')->name('category.store');
Route::get('dashboard/categories', 'App\Http\Controllers\CategoryController@index')->name('categories');
Route::get('dashboard/categories/{id}', 'App\Http\Controllers\CategoryController@show')->name('category');
Route::get('dashboard/categories/edit/{id}', 'App\Http\Controllers\CategoryController@edit')->name('category.edit');
Route::post('dashboard/categories/edit/{id}', 'App\Http\Controllers\CategoryController@update')->name('category.update');
Route::get('dashboard/categories/delete/{id}', 'App\Http\Controllers\CategoryController@destroy')->name('category.destroy');
Route::get('dashboard/forum/new', 'App\Http\Controllers\ForumController@create')->name('forum.new');
Route::post('dashboard/forum/new', 'App\Http\Controllers\ForumController@store')->name('forum.store');
Route::get('dashboard/forums', 'App\Http\Controllers\ForumController@index')->name('forums');
Route::get('dashboard/forums/{id}', 'App\Http\Controllers\ForumController@edit')->name('forum');
Route::get('dashboard/forums/edit/{id}', 'App\Http\Controllers\ForumController@edit')->name('forum.edit');
Route::post('dashboard/forums/update/{id}', 'App\Http\Controllers\ForumController@update')->name('forum.update');
Route::get('dashboard/forums/delete/{id}', 'App\Http\Controllers\ForumController@destroy')->name('forum.destroy');
Route::get('client/topic/new/{id}', 'App\Http\Controllers\DiscussionController@create')->name('topic.new');
Route::post('client/topic/new', 'App\Http\Controllers\DiscussionController@store')->name('topic.store');
Route::get('client/topic/{id}', 'App\Http\Controllers\DiscussionController@show')->name('topic');
Route::post('client/topic/reply/{id}', 'App\Http\Controllers\DiscussionController@reply')->name('topic.reply');
Route::get('/topic/reply/delete/{id}', 'App\Http\Controllers\DiscussionController@destroy')->name('reply.delete');
Route::get('/updates', 'App\Http\Controllers\DiscussionController@updates');
Route::post('user/update/{id}', 'App\Http\Controllers\UserController@update')->name("user.update");
Route::get('/dashboard/users/{id}', 'App\Http\Controllers\DashboardController@show');
Route::post('/dashboard/users/{id}', 'App\Http\Controllers\DashboardController@destroy')->name('user.delete');
Route::prefix('admin')->group(function() {
    Route::get('/login','Auth\AdminLoginController@showLoginForm')->name('admin.login');
    Route::post('/login', 'Auth\AdminLoginController@login')->name('admin.login.submit');
    Route::get('logout/', 'Auth\AdminLoginController@logout')->name('admin.logout');
    Route::get('/', 'Auth\AdminController@index')->name('admin.dashboard');
   }) ;
```

UserController

````
``` <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\User;

class UserController extends Controller
{
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $input = $request->all();
        $user = User::find($id);
        $user->fill($input)->save();
        toastr()->success('Your details have been updated successfully!');
        return back();
    }
}
```
````

HomeController

````
``` <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\Discussion;

class HomeController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    /**
     * Show the application dashboard.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Support\Renderable
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $latest_user_post = Discussion::where('user_id', auth()->id())->latest()->first();
        $latest = Discussion::latest()->first();
        return view('home', compact('latest_user_post', 'latest'));
    }
}
 
```
````

But since I made his page 127.0.0.1:8000/dashboard/home is white and I have errors when I create an account I have a first error:
Trying to get property 'user' of non-object (View: /home/project/Pictures/forum/resources/views/home.blade.php)

if I comment it I have another error that appears it is this:
Trying to get property 'created_at' of non-object (View: /home/project/Pictures/forum/resources/views/home.blade.php)

Etc... I have had errors like this since I tried to make only the admin can this connect to the dashboard. I am a beginner I do not know how to adjust it, I am not sure I also have a route error. I tried to follow different tutorial on google to learn laravel until it was okay, if someone can help me and explain the problem it would be kind.

Comment: All the code I changed is in the link I put, I didn't have enough room to put everything here. home2 is the home of admin it is located views/admin/pages link = we.tl/t-jdiPhXsGEX

Comment: your error itself says that it is accessing the property of a variable which is null or it is non object, in most cases the variable is null. try checking you code and see if you missed passing the variable or have a typo in the variable name